# malloc, C, односвязный список

Tags: c, malloc

Есть интовый массив. Есть функция создания односвязного списка из этого массива и ней есть цикл for в котором используется malloc:

```
        struct item *first = NULL, *last = NULL, *tmp;

        for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){
                tmp = malloc(sizeof(*tmp));
                tmp->data = arr[i];
                tmp->next = NULL;
                if(last){
                        last->next = tmp;
                        last = last->next;
                } else
                        first = last = tmp;
        }
```

Функция возвращает указатель на этот список.
Вопрос в следующем: Нужно ли как-то после этого чистить память с помощью free(или после завершения программы память сама освободится) и если да, то как это делать грамотно?

Можно, конечно, через цикл, но есть ли иной способ?

Comment: После завершения программы память освободится, однако все равно нужно очищать список, удаляя каждый выделенный буфер и затирая невалидные указатели.

Comment: в си работает принцип - сам выделил, сам освободил. Никто и никогда не будет освобождать "магически". Если выделялось в цикле, то в 99% случаев и освобождать нужно в цикле, хотя можно и рекурсией (но это тот же цикл, просто может ещё и со stackoverflow упасть:) )